# Get Daily Active Users data via API in Fabric

Tags: crashlytics

We are using fabric for crash analytics. wondering if we can get the daily/monthly active uses from Farbic to report whats the conversion look like via API.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Todd from Fabric - right now we do not offer an API however it's something we're looking into.